# Kotlin Extension functions to split big classes

Tags: android, kotlin

Recently at my company a debate started after reviewing a different approach for writing heavy duty classes.

A big Java class holding component specific logic (no standard OOP principles made sense) had to be rewritten in Kotlin. The solution provided was splitting the logic in categories and the categories into separate files with internal extension functions to the main class.

Example:

```
Main.kt
class BigClass {
  // internal fields exposed to the extension functions in different files

  // Some main logic here
}


BusinessLogic.kt
internal fun BigClass.handleBussinessCase() {
 // Complex business logic handled here accessing the exposed internal fields from BigClass
}
```

What are your thoughts on this? I haven't seen it used anywhere maybe for a good reason, but the alternative of thousand lines classes seems worse.

Comment: If you can split the logic into "categories" then why can't you split it into classes?

Comment: I'd have to pass multiple references from the main class, my main concern is with readability. Splitting into multiple files makes the code a bit hard to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider that an extension function is nothing more than a function with an implicit first parameter which is referenced with `this`.

So in your case you'd have something like:

```
internal fun handleBussinessCase(ref: BigClass)
```

which would translate to *Java* as:

```
static void handleBussinessCase(BigClass ref)
```

But this could be assumed to be a delegate pattern, which could be encapsulated much cleaner in *Kotlin* as well.

Since the properties have to be *internal* anyhow, you could just inject these as a `data class` into smaller use-cases. If you define an interface around these (which would make the properties *public* though), you could create a delegate pattern with it and still reference each property with `this` in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts on making extension functions for the class:

- It will be a utility function that will operate with the object you're extending, it will not be an object function, meaning that it will have access to only `public` methods and properties;
- If you're planning to use class that being extended in unit tests, these methods (extensions) will be harder to mock;
- Most likely they wont behave as you expect when used with inherited objects.

Maybe I missed something, so please read more about extensions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).